# How to add things under the namespace App in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

What do I have to do to be able to use App\Traits\Uuids;

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use app\Traits\Uuids;
```

The uuids trait is under ..\app\Traits\Uuid.php so it only works if use app\Traits with a small cap.

If I use the namespace

```
namespace App\Traits;
```

instead of

```
namespace app\Traits;
```

I am using Composer version 2.1.3 2021-06-09 16:31:20 and when I run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

it will returns

```
 "Class App\Traits\Uuids located in [...]/app/Traits\Uuid.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping."
```

Comment: If this is a package, there isn't much you can do unless you want to create a pull request or fork the repo. If it is your own code, change the namespace to use a capital `A`.

Comment: This has also been a problem for packages that hook into the `User.php` model; in pervious versions of Laravel, this was `App\User`, but in Laravel 8, it's `App\Models\User`. Open an issue on the GitHub Repo and inform them of the incompatibility issue, hopefully they can fix it :)

Comment: I cannot change it to App, I get does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping. and PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'Uuids' not found in ... but it's going to be a nightmare to remember to declare App or app. what am I missing? any suggestions?

Comment: *"I cannot change it to App, I get does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard."* - Huh? Practically everything in Laravel is `namespace App\...;`, and I'm looking at a custom trait of mine in `app/Traits` called `OverridesDefault.php`, `trait OverridesDefault { ... }` with `namespace App\Traits;`. When I want to use it, I use `use App\Traits\OverridesDefault;`... No PSR-4 autoloading issues or anything. You might need to modify your question a bit more to show the issue.

Comment: when i use the namespace "App\Traits;" . composer dump-autoload complains "Class App\Traits\Uuids located in [...]/app/Traits\Uuid.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping." If I declare it under "app\Traits"  it goes away. I don't know what the issue is. i can't rewrite my question. I want to know what i have to do to use App\Traits. how is all the built-in namespace uses App? I think there is an alias that uses App and repoint it to illuminate.

Comment: thanks @TimLewis I figured it out. I did not know that the file name had to have the same spelling as the end portion of the namespace. my file was Uuid.php and not Uuids.php

Comment: Ah yes, that would do it :) Any deviation between class/traitname from filename will trigger PSR-4 warnings like that. A common one is something like `ApiController.php` vs `APIController.php`, and `class ApiController` vs `class APIController`, etc. Regardless, glad you got it working! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to matching the caps, as suggested, the filename must match the class name.

renaming the php file to Uuid.php removed the psr-4 error.

composer.json has a provision that renames App to app/ and that part works out of the box.

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",

}
```